# Half Poisson summation

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-distributions

Suppose $f$ is a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}$. Is there a closed formula for $$\sum_0^\infty \hat{f}(n)$$ where $\hat{f}$ is the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that ${\bf 1}_{{\bf R}_+} \hat{f} = \widehat{\hat{{\bf 1}_{{\bf R}_-}}* f}$ and apply the usual Poisson formula to 
$\hat{{\bf 1}_{{\bf R}_-}}f$.

Depending on your convention, there is an explicit formula for $\hat{\bf 1}_{{\bf R}_-}$. With the $2\pi$ inside the exponential, 
$$
\hat{\bf 1}_{{\bf R}_-}(\xi) = {1\over 2i\pi\xi} - {1\over 2}\delta(\xi)
$$
Assuming I have put my $2\pi$ at the right location, this should lead to the following formula. 
$$
\sum_{k\geq0} \hat{f}(k) = \sum_{n\in {\bf Z}} \ (f*{1\over 2i\pi \xi})(n) - {1\over2} f(n)
$$
The convolution is understood in the sense of distribution theory.
You probably need some extra regularity on $f$ to compensate for the discontinuity of the Heaviside function together with the hypothesis that $\hat{f}(0) = 0$. You can interpolate the step function with an affine one to alleviate this difficulty but then the transform has a slightly more complicated form.